# Symfony / Form Type - not populating data for edit form for datetime in single_text widget style

Tags: forms, symfony, datetime, format, widget

Maybe something simple I missed? But I have a CRUD form based on an entity and everything seems to work fine. The object can be created, edited and updated fine. But when I change the default widget style on a datetime field the date data no longer populates into the edit form, and rather displays the date format string 'dd/mm/yyyy'.

Is there something obvious going wrong here?

In the entity the property is this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $createdDate;
```

Getters and setters:

```
public function getCreatedDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
    return $this->createdDate;
}

public function setCreatedDate(?\DateTimeInterface $createdDate): self
{
    $this->createdDate = $createdDate;

    return $this;
}
```

In the form builder:

```
->add('createdDate', DateType::class, [
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'required' => false,
        ])
```

Generated HTML:

```
<div>
    <label for="hmr_core_createdDate" class="required">Created date</label>
    <input type="date" id="hmr_core_createdDate" 
        name="hmr_core[createdDate]" 
        required="required">
</div>
```

CreatedDate in the Request Attributes:

```
-createdDate: DateTime @1551092357 {#975 ▼
date: 2019-02-25 21:29:17.0 Australia/Melbourne (+11:00)
```

Debug output:

[debug1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phd3B.png)
[debug2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP0Jg.png)

It doesn't seem to matter if I add options like format etc. As soon as I delete the widget line or set it to choice it all works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also doesn't seem to matter if the type in the entity is either 'date' or 'datetime'. NB. changing from default widget which is the choice type to single text.

Comment: Could you show the (controller) code using the form and also setter, getter and constructor from the entity?

Comment: Since your property is nullable, is there a chance the value you are testing is actually null in the database and before it was doing something wrong, e.g. always create a DateTime object without passing the value making it fall back to "now"?

Comment: @dbrumann - I know it's not null in the database because as soon as I change the widget type to 'choice' the correct date is output. I can also see the correct datetime in the parameters being passed to the form... (and I also checked the database)

Comment: Can you please show what the generated HTML for this field looks like? And please also check what is displayed as the model data, norm data and view data for this particular field in the Symfony profiler.

Comment: Hi @xabbuh, I have updated that information now...

Comment: Can you please also show the profiler output after the form has been submitted?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it. Somehow the entity object had been deleted from being passed as a parameter from the controller, I am not sure how it was recieving data in the case of the three drop down widgets but there it is.